# make javascript include fit in body of responsive site

Tags: javascript, css, include, responsive

How would I make a javascript include with within the body of my responsive site? Is there a way to resize? Here is an example of the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://adn.ebay.com/files/js/min/jquery-1.6.2-min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://adn.ebay.com/files/js/min/ebay_activeContent-min.js'></script>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxcustomId=Books&keyword=%28finance+book%2Ccollectable+books%2Cself+help+books%29&width=336&height=280&font=1&textColor=333366&linkColor=333333&arrowColor=A7A7A7&color1=Eb9641&color2=[COLORTWO]&format=ImageLink&contentType=TEXT_AND_IMAGE&enableSearch=y&usePopularSearches=n&freeShipping=n&topRatedSeller=n&itemsWithPayPal=n&descriptionSearch=n&showKwCatLink=n&excludeCatId=&excludeKeyword=&catId=267&disWithin=200&ctx=n&autoscroll=n&title=Books&flashEnabled=' + isFlashEnabled + '&pageTitle=' + _epn__pageTitle + '&cachebuster=' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000 )) + '">\x3C/script>' );
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just put the script tag in your head. `document.write` writes the entire document again. Avoid using it, altogether.

Comment: `<script>` tags don't occupy 'space' in the DOM. If you're talking about restyling your eBay button, that's done via `CSS`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge - thank you. I'm pretty newb compared to most users on here. I've been able to align Amazon links without css; just <div> tags. Do you think that would work?

Comment: @RobertTanguay -- It depends what you mean by 'align'. `<div>` tags are just block-level vertical separators; they won't work for horizontal alignment. Also, considering you're using a `document.write` they wouldn't really work at all (as they'd get overwritten as mentioned by PHPglue). I'd really recommend using something like `innerHTML` instead of `document.write()`, or learning some basic CSS to cover this (which would be incredibly useful in the future). You can use the F12 Developer Tools to find out the exact elements that you need to target with either CSS or JavaScript :)